# copy output of terminal in question

Tags: clipboard

I failed to copy/paste print screen output in my question box. How to copy/paste output of a shell command from terminal screen to askubuntu question box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, usually with the `terminal`, simply highlighting text can copy it and as mentioned, middle clicking will paste the selected text.

Comment: If that worked for you, would you mind checking off my answer?

Answer (score 7):

1. Just select the region of text in the Terminal.
2. Right click on it.
3. Select `Copy`.
4. Right click on Askubuntu question area.
5. Select `Paste`.

Also you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste

** You can also `Paste` it at [pastebin.ubuntu.com](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com) and put the link at askubuntu question.

** Also you can use the application `pastebinit` to send the terminal output directly to the pastebin.ubuntu.com

```
sudo apt-get install pastebinit
```

Comment: You can also use pastebinit.

Comment: sure, pastebin is helpful for lengthy output.

Comment: You can also press **Ctrl-Shift-C** to copy from a terminal (and similarly with V to paste) - this helps on laptops where trying to right click might destroy the selection.

Answer (score 3):

In terminal the shortcuts are a bit different: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> for copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> for paste (because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> are already occupied by other functions). A very detailed answer has been posted [here](https://superuser.com/a/421468).

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you running? If it's Linux, and you're using mouse, middle-click should also work in most apps: select some text, then left-click where it must be pasted, and middle-click to paste.